# How does the splice work in Function Component(hooks) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, splice

Please help me out to understand this case.
According to Hooks:

When we declare a state variable with "useState", it returns a pair — an array with two items. The first item is the current value, and the second is a **function that lets us update it**.

on the other hand, The stateless component calculates the internal state of the component but does not have the **authority to change state**.
but in blew example I update my const by `splice` and `setData`

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([
  { name: "first",id: 1},
  { name: "two", id: 2 }
]);
const addData = () => {
var newVal={ name: "Four", id: 4 };
data.splice(data.lenght,0,newVal);

setData([...data,{name:"three",id:3}]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
};
return (
 <div>
   <ul>
     {data.map((item,index) => {
       return <li>{item.name} {index}</li>;
     })}
   </ul>
   <div onClick={()=>addData()} > add to list</div>
 </div>
);
}
```

I can't understand, How does `splice` work in function component(Hooks)?
so why do we need to used `setData`?

you can watch my code [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qe6vt8?file=src%2FApp.js) in stackblitz.com
when click to add to list, both ways are work.

Thank you.